# Error getting object filename.xlsx from bucket xxx. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a new AWS S3 file using Visual studio and aws toolkit and it generated the following code.

```
public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var s3Event = evnt.Records?[0].S3;
    if(s3Event == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        var response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);
        return response.Headers.ContentType;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        var msg = $"Error getting object {s3Event.Object.Key} from bucket {s3Event.Bucket.Name}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.";
        context.Logger.LogLine(msg);
        context.Logger.LogLine(e.Message);
        context.Logger.LogLine(e.StackTrace);
        Log.Error($"S3 notification error: {msg}\n{e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
        throw;
    }
}
```

However, it got the following error in CloudWatch when I uploaded a file to the S3 bucket,

> Error getting object filename.xlsx from bucket myBucket. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.

And the bucket and the lambda are both in Oregon?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue. In my case, the problem was the execution role of my lambda function. Apparently, it didn't have enough permissions. To solve the problem, I first deleted all the policies from the role and added the three followings:

- AWSLambdaFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- CloudWatchFullAccess

I gave it some time, reran my lambda function and this time it worked. This way, I made sure the problem was due to permissions. 
But it is not a good practice to leave the permissions that open. From here, you can start restricting permissions of your lambda function's execution role based on your own use case to find the least permissions that would do the job for you.